# Call multiple functions inside Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq expression which works on its own:

```
var query = from c in db.crawljobs
            where c.fk_members_id == uid
            select c;
```

Now I want to add the results of two other functions inside this expression.

```
public int GetNumCrawlResults(int jobId)
{
    return SomeInt();
}

public int GetNumPagesCrawled(int jobId)
{
    return SomeInt();
}
```

So I tried something like this:

```
var query = from c in db.crawljobs                     
            from cr in GetNumCrawlResults(c.id)
            from cp in GetNumPagesCrawled(c.id)
            where c.fk_members_id == uid 
            select c;
```

I am getting the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   GetNumCrawlResults(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but you have to use `.ToList()` before calling your own functions. The functions that you call have to be valid in SQL for Linq to Entities to work right.  However, Linq to Objects will handle that just fine if you do `.ToList()` first.